# Conditional statement for dates

Tags: php, conditional-tags, comparison

Im trying to create a conditional statement comparing two dates.
I have a ACF custom date field as one date, and then comparing against the current date.

Below is what i have and iv echoed both $date and $currentdate and they both come out in the same format, so im not sure why it wont work. They both output in the format like: 20170105 which i beleive they need to be to compare.

```
<?php
    $currentdate = current_time('Ymd');
    $date = get_field('course_start_date', false, false);
    $date = new DateTime($date);


    if ($currentdate > $date) {
    echo ' - Started.';  
    } else {
      echo ' - Not started.';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Do an `echo` or do a `print_r` on `$date` and give the value please.

Comment: @the_dramatist sure. $currentdate = 20170105 and $date = 20170201. Obvious the $date changes depending on which post. But i have two posts, one where the $date is larger than $currentdate and one that is smaller than, but my conditional statement says the same

Comment: With those values, the conditional statement works as expected? Can you debug with real data that actually doesn't work? Which date format do you have in `course_start_date`? Why do you post in your comment integer values saying they are returned by `current_time()` and `DateTime` when those functions return strings? Please, [edit the question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/251387/edit) to add additional information.

Comment: I just tested this in my system and it worked as it is expected. Please show us what error your system is throwing ?

Comment: Ahh stupidly i removed the $date = new DateTime($date); line and that has resolved it. Sorry i mis-understood the ACF documentation clearly. Thanks for your help all

Answer (score 2):

instead of   `$currentdate = current_time('Ymd');`

you can use   `$currentdate = new DateTime();`

so the Final Solution should be as like given below

```
<?php
    $currentdate = new DateTime();
    $date = get_field('course_start_date', false, false);
    $date = new DateTime($date);


    if ($currentdate > $date) {
    echo ' - Started.';  
    } else {
      echo ' - Not started.';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please merge your two accounts